# JPPF ( jppf.org) Could someone please share their experience using JPPF?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am considering using JPPF for a application which runs a set of tasks in parallel. I was wondering if any one has had any recent experience using the framework. In particular I am interested in 
1. Aspects around "robustness" for example recovery from failure of nodes.
2. Running tasks on 500+ nodes.
3. Network traffic

Comment: Have you considered asking, or at least searching, in their forums?